# How to encrypt a long string with RSA using a custom public key and padding format

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

so I ran into the problem that I need to encrypt a string with a size of 450 to 470 bytes. I only have a public key from the server hoster where I want to send an encrypted login message. The problem is the public key is not a standard one, it is modified by the server hoster to meet their cryptosystem. They used Java to do the encryption but I creating a software plugin in c#. So how can I encrypt with their given key my string?

Public key:

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

They told me their key is separated like that:

48015250          4 bytes       "Magic"

01                1 byte        Version number

00000101          4 bytes       Length of modulus: 0x0101 = 257 bytes

00970348...C1D  257 bytes       Modulus

00000003          4 bytes       Length of exponent: 0x0003 = 3 bytes

010001            3 bytes       Exponent: 0x010001 = 65537

I created a public key in c# with the exponent and modulus from their key

```
private static string m_strModulus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
private static string m_strExponent = "010001";
string xmlPublicKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>" + m_strModulus + "</Modulus><Exponent>" + m_strExponent + "</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
```

and used RSACryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(myOwnPublicXmlKeyGeneratedFromTheirs) to encrypt the login message.

```
rsa.FromXmlString(xmlPublicKey);
```

since i have a large string i encrypted the whole thing in blocks of 245 bytes like that:

```
private const int m_nKeySize = 2048;  // The RSA key length
private const int _EncryptionBufferSize = 245;
private const int _DecryptionBufferSize = 256;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
        //Create a buffer with the maximum allowed size
        byte[] buffer = new byte[_EncryptionBufferSize];
        int pos = 0;
        int copyLength = buffer.Length;
        while (true)
        {
          //Check if the bytes left to read is smaller than the buffer size, then limit the buffer size to the number of bytes left
          if (pos + copyLength > byData.Length)
          {
            copyLength = byData.Length - pos;
          }
          //Create a new buffer that has the correct size
          buffer = new byte[copyLength];
          //Copy as many bytes as the algorithm can handle at a time, iterate until the whole input array is encoded
          Array.Copy(byData, pos, buffer, 0, copyLength);
          //Start from here in next iteration
          pos += copyLength;
          //Encrypt the data using the public key and add it to the memory buffer
          //_DecryptionBufferSize is the size of the encrypted data
          ms.Write(rsa.Encrypt(buffer, false), 0, _DecryptionBufferSize);
          //Clear the content of the buffer, otherwise we could end up copying the same data during the last iteration
          Array.Clear(buffer, 0, copyLength);
          //Check if we have reached the end, then exit
          if (pos >= byData.Length)
            break;
        }
```

They also mentioned to use the TBC(Trailing Bit Complement) padding algorithm and I didn't find any implementation for this in C# only in java which I cant use.

The server responds me with the error that the public key is wrong or outdated or the syntax is wrong of the message. I can already communicate with the server non encrypted and so the text to encrypt should be fine.

As far as I know, I'm not correctly using their public key because its custom made for their purpose.

Has anybody a clue how to solve this particular case?

Edit:

i converted the hex values of the modulus and the exponent to base64 values, i forgot to mention that. I used the following method:

```
public static string HexStringtoB64String(string input)
{
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(HexStringToByteArray(input));
}
```

and used them just before creating the rsa instance like this:

```
m_strModulus = HexStringtoB64String(m_strModulus);
m_strExponent = HexStringtoB64String(m_strExponent);
```

Comment: I think you need to use RSA rsa = RSA.Create(string); to get correct type.  See following to msdn webpage to get the string value : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.create?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_AsymmetricAlgorithm_Create_System_String_

Comment: Your key is made of Hex chars (Base16) , the RSA Xml format uses Base64.

Comment: @jdweng - how will selecting an `algorithmName` help?

Comment: The key isn't derived from default RSA Algorithm and giving an exception.  Must use a non standard RSA algoritm.  Read the link I provided.

Comment: thanks i will have a look into it and let you know if it helped.

Comment: I'd use [`importparameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importparameters?view=netframework-4.7.2) myself, then you can just use a structure instead of some ill defined XML format. As for the padding method, that kind of padding doesn't make sense for RSA; you need to ask them to formally describe their input format, or if that isn't available (I bet it isn't) an example.

Comment: Until such a spec or example is provided I've decided to vote this as off topic. Just testing padding schemes on the input string, encrypting it, and doing this until the correct ciphertext is produced doesn't sound useful.

Comment: i will give the importparameters a try. Im also about to ask if they got something to explain there procedure to generate their key or if possible an assembly for c# to do so, else im kinda stuck.